# keep the area of a subplot unchanged while changing the ticklabels size

Tags: matplotlib

In `matplotlib`, if I increase the size of the ticklabels, the size of the subplots will keep unchanged but the whole figure will expand itself.

For example:

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

fig, (ax1, ax2) = plt.subplots(2, 1)
ax2.set_yticklabels(['a long and big label'], fontsize=26)
```

[image]

I want to know how to set the subplots to automatically adjust their size to accommodate the ticklabels so that the whole area a subplot takes will keep unchanged, like the following:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First one should note that the total area a subplot takes *is* unchanged by default. The code from the question result in

[image]

where the label is simply cut. When the code is run in jupyter notebook with the inline backend, the resulting png image is however expanded to contain everything, even parts initially outside the figure.

You can automatically adjust all the subplots to nicely fit into the figure via `constrained_layout` or `tight_layout()`. E.g.

```
fig, (ax1, ax2) = plt.subplots(2, 1, constrained_layout=True)
# ...
```

or

```
fig, (ax1, ax2) = plt.subplots(2, 1)
ax2.set_yticklabels(['a long and big label'], fontsize=26)
fig.tight_layout()
```

[image]

There is however no automatic way to only adjust one of the subplots independent of the others. For such case one would need to manually calculate the space needed.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

fig = plt.figure()
gs = fig.add_gridspec(2,2)

ax1 = fig.add_subplot(gs[0,:])
ax2 = fig.add_subplot(gs[1,1])
ax2.set_yticklabels(['a long and big label'], fontsize=26)

fig.canvas.draw()
bb = ax2.yaxis.get_tightbbox(fig.canvas.get_renderer())
labelwidth = fig.transFigure.inverted().transform([bb.width, 0])[0]
axwidth = ax1.get_position().width

gs.set_width_ratios([labelwidth, axwidth-labelwidth] )
ax2.set_position(gs[1,1].get_position(fig))

plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: Thx, very helpful like always. Could pls also add an example if I set labels for both ax1 and ax2 with different fontsize? Is that a way to align the labels?